# Getting errors while using React testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsC2S.png)When we render any component for testing getting the below errors,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0jZn.png)

• If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

```
You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: C:\Users\H525043\ReactApp\uma\monorepo_ui\node_modules\@testing-library\react\node_modules\@types\react-dom\client.d.ts: Unexpected token (7:13)

   5 | // See https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom/client.js to see how the exports are declared,
   6 |
>  7 | import React = require('react');
     |              ^
   8 | export interface HydrationOptions {
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use import and require in a single statement.
Either import it using ES6 syntax `import React from 'react'` or just require it if you are using require.js

```
var react = require('react'); //require.js
import React from 'react'; //ES6 import
```

Comment: But these code is from client.d.ts file from node modules ,node_modules\@testing-library\react\node_modules\@types\react-dom\
We are using the "@testing-library/react": "11.1.2", version.